# Grub install failing on Ubuntu 20.04.01 live server iso - using EFI

Tags: server, grub2, uefi

I am trying to install ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso on my laptop, which has EFI BIOS. It looks like it is failing at `install-grub: FAIL: curtin command curthoooks`. I believe I did everything correct for setting up the partitions. Any ideas how to fix?

[image: boot1]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a failure in the [same location, for the same reason](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1856038); different platform. For the second image, would we benefit from seeing a little earlier than the tail of the error ...

Comment: I had that same curtain error with the 18 LTS iso live server install. Does this mean it won't be getting fixed anytime soon? Should I look for a diff distro?

Comment: Dman, that was resolved; if you want to use the exact same version as you are currently using then I'd look at that report, to see how it was resolved. --- A newer version is usually better (subject to newer bugs) and would incorporate all prior fixes.